# keep order as it was saved and keep only unique words in text file list

Tags: python-3.x

need sort lines in order in which they were saved in txt file, just new line comes from below and save this order after remove similar words. so if I add words in loop one by one

```
line A 
line B 
line C 
line D 
line E
```

here I got three solutions, but nothing works for me correct

first keeps only unique words;

```
with open('C:\my_path\doc.txt', 'r') as lines: 
    lines_set = {line.strip() for line in lines}
with open(''D:\path\file.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in lines_set:
        out.write(line + '\n')
```

but destroys order:

```
1. line B
2. line E
3. line C
4. line D
5. line A
```

second keeps order but same words too:

```
with open('C:\my_path\doc.txt', 'r') as lines:
    lines_set = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() not in lines_set:  
            lines_set.append(line.strip())
```

last one works well, but with input text:

```
   with open('C:\my_path\doc.txt', 'r') as lines:
       lines_set = []
       for line in lines:
            if line.strip() not in lines_set: 
                lines_set.append(line.strip())
```

in some cases I have no any input, and also have different input, so need somehow sort ordered list itself

can you help me figure out  with it please

Comment: The last two appear to be the same? I'm assuming a pasting error. I'm not sure what your issue is, do you want a sorted list, or a list in the original order?

Comment: with each cycle I've add a new word in text  file, but under a certain condition in a certain or each cycle, I want remove duplicated words. I need a continually expanding list with one line but keep it in original order as it runs just each new line comes from below after each removing of same words

Comment: so original order I guess but with active addition of new line below previous

Comment: Simply build the list, then run it through another function to remove duplicates. You could then call a sort of `removeDuplicates(list)` function.

Comment: can you show me on this example please  how to do it because I've tried but nothing

Comment: despite me still being unsure as to what you're asking. I gave it a shot, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`loadLines` is almost as your function you show twice, but it allows duplicates. `removeDuplicates` strips duplicates. `saveLines` writes a list to a file, deliminating by newline.  All functions preserve order.

```
#Load lines with duplicates
def loadLines(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as lines:
        lines_set = []
        for line in lines:
            lines_set.append(line.strip())
    return lines_set

#Search list "l", return list without duplicates.
def removeDuplicates(l):
    out = list(set(l))
    for i in enumerate(out):
        out[i[0]] = l.index(i[1])
    out.sort()
    for i in enumerate(out):
        out[i[0]] = l[i[1]]
    return out

#Write the lines "l" to filepath "f"
def saveLines(f, l):
    open(f, 'w').write('\n'.join(l))

lines = loadLines('doc.txt')
print(lines)
stripped_lines = removeDuplicates(lines)
print(stripped_lines)
saveLines('doc.txt', stripped_lines)
```

Comment: A better way than how I do the sort would be to not replace out's data in the first loop but instead make a new list and sort out based on the order that new list would be sorted. I'm not sure how to do that easily in Python but that'd remove a loop.

Comment: yes yes that it, bot I don't want  return it, I want remove this duplicates inside the file.txt exactly with same result how your code returns it, (with original sequence and free from duplicates and without attach to the current input) so just with  one difference, do it inside the text document

Comment: @L_Oni, you just want a basic save function? That should only take a few seconds.

Comment: cycle creates word and word must be stored in text document line by line new below the previous natural way one after another. but sometimes same duplicated word must be saved in list too, and not one or two just unlimited number, until at a certain cycle does not form a specific condition to delete all duplicates at once together and keep only unique, this one of reasons why I don't want use current input. so your code is perfect and answers on this goal, but can you show me how to do the same inside the text document itself

Comment: @L_Oni, I'm not sure what you're asking. To edit a document you first load the data, modify that data, then write it back to the document. The `savelines(f, l)` function I've provided does that write. So effectively this does do the same inside the text document itself. Edit: Perhaps you missed my updated answer since your last comment  :p.

Comment: yes sorry I missed you addition. ok with `savelines(f, l) ` if I going to use your code without any change, except of course the real path to doc, now inside the text document, in which I have words, line under line: word 1 word 2 word 3 word 2 word 1, after I run your code I must have in text doc this result: word 1 word 2 word 3. but I have same duplicates in text document, maybe because I'm on windows... my path looks like this: `(D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\file.txt)` I've tried it with two slashes, but same
 or I don't know, maybe I'm doing something wrong again

Comment: @L_Oni, great! Please accept my answer if it solves your question :).